# Find and Replace on PowerPoint Excel Worksheet for a Chart

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

So this code will run a Find and Replace on PowerPoint charts. the goal is to replace the x-axis labels. The issue I'm having is that I get this popping up: `We couldn't find anything to replace. Click options for more ways to search."`
It pops up every time the chart doesn't have the word I'm looking for. So I added `rngFound`. I want to be able to say "If word is Found then Replace" instead of having my Replace just do everything at once. 
So I went and added `Set rngFound =  Worksheets(1).objRange.Find(fndList)`. But it's not working. I suspect rngFound isn't actually doing anything for me, and would like any sort of help with this issue. Thank you in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub findAndReplaceChrt()

'Timer start
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer

Dim pptPres As Object
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shpe As Shape
Dim c As Chart

Dim sht As Object
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim listArray As Long
Dim rngFound As Variant

fndList = Array("Red", "Purple")
rplcList = Array("red", "blue")

'Make pptPres the ppt active
Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

'Loop through each sld and check for chart title, grab avgScore values and create pptTable to paste into ppt chart
For Each sld In pptPres.Slides

    'searches through shapes in the slide
    For Each shpe In sld.Shapes

        'Checks if shape is a Charts and has a Chart Title
        If Not shpe.HasChart Then GoTo nxtShpe

        Set c = shpe.Chart

        If Not c.ChartType = xlPie Then

            ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
            c.ChartData.Activate

            'Loop through each item in Array lists
            For listArray = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)

                Set rngFound =  Worksheets(1).objRange.Find(fndList)

                If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                    Worksheets(1).Cells.Replace What:=fndList(listArray), Replacement:=rplcList(listArray), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
                End If

            Next listArray

            c.ChartData.Workbook.Close

        End If

nxtShpe:
    Next shpe

Next sld


'End Timer
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: If you turn off `Application.DisplayAlerts`, do you still get that message?

Comment: Also, have you done F8 and stepped through to see if the line If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then jumps to the End If?

Comment: @dwirony It doesn't work because Application.DisplayAlerts would target PowerPoint since that's where I'm running it from, and the cahrt is an excel chart that it brings up. QHarr, I have tried that, and it does do it, but it only does it if the chart data is blank. If the chart data has anything in it, then rngFound will have a range attached to it (regardless of if it finds listArray or not)

Comment: `Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False` Worked. Whoops forgot I could just do that. Thank you! @dwirony